How does substitution for change of variables for cubics work?
I'm reading the following set of notes where they prove the following theorem

Theorem 5.1.4: The equation of an irreducible cubic with a[t] flex point [..P..?] can
be written as
$$y^2z = x^3+ ax^2z + bxz^2 + cz^3$$
after a change of coordinates.


Proof: Let $C$ be the curve defined by the equation
$$a_0x^3+a_1x^2y +a_2x^2z+a_3xy^2+a_4xyz+a_5xz^2+a_6y^3+a_7y^2z+a_8yz^2+a_9z^3 = 0$$
Assume that $[0 : 1 : 0]$ is a flex point with tangent line $z = 0$. Then, when restricting the equation to the line, we need to get $x^3 = 0$, forcing $a_1 = a_3 = a_6 = 0$. If $a_7 = 0$ we get that the restriction of the equation of $C$ to the line $x = 0$ is $a_8yz^2 + a_9z^3 = 0$. Thus $x = 0$ is a second tangent line to $C$ at $P$. Since $P$ is a flex point, it is non-singular and we deduce that $a_7 \neq 0$. We can now change change variables with $y = y' +\alpha x+\beta z$ so that there will be no other terms involving $y'$ than $(y')^2$. Thus we get to the desired normal form.

My question is the following. I agree that it makes sense that we must take $z=0$ and substitute.
Q.1. Why do we need $X^3=0$?
Q.2 Why is x=0 the second tangent line? How are we finding the tangent lines? Doesn't a flex point imply that a tangent line hits the point with multiplicity 3? Where is that fact being used?
Thank you so much in advance!

The last part of your second question indeed answers the first question.

So if I understand correctly, my flex point is $[0:1:0]$ and so $x=0$ and since it hits with multiplicity 3, we must have $x^3=0$ necessarily? Does that also mean $z^3=0$ and $(y-1)^3=0$?
